# mysql query trying to search by alias involving CASES and aggregate functions

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables left joined. The query is grouped by the left table's ID column. The right table has a date column called close_date. The problem is, if there are any right table records that have not been closed (thus having a close_date of 0000-00-00), then I do not want any of the left table records to be shown, and if there are NO right table records with a close_date of 0000-00-00, I would like only the right table record with the MAX close date to be returned.

So for simplicity sake, let's say the tables look like this:

```
Table1
id
1
2

Table2
table1_id | close_date
1         | 0000-00-00
1         | 2010-01-01
2         | 2010-01-01
2         | 2010-01-02
```

I would like the query to only return this:

```
Table1.id | Table2.close_date
2         | 2010-01-02
```

I tried to come up with an answer using aliased CASES and aggregate functions, but I could not search by the result, and I was attempting not to make a 3 mile long query to solve the problem. I looked through a few of the related posts on here, but none seem to meet the criteria of this particular case.

Comment: Magic constants are evil. Why not use the method the database is designed for, a NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       MAX(t2.close_date)
  FROM TABLE1 t1
  JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t2.table1_id = t1.id
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM TABLE2 t
                   WHERE t.table1_id = t1.id
                     AND t.closed_date = '0000-00-00')
```

The '0000-00-00' should be implicitly converted by MySQL to a DATETIME.  If not, cast the value to DATETIME.

Comment: I like this a lot. I started trying to do something like this with a NOT IN until I saw your answer, which seems to be much more elegant. I tried it out, and at first impression it seems to work, although I am looking for a few test cases to spot check and verify. I will check this answer once I do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select table1id,close_date form table2 
where close_date= (select max(close_date) from table2) or close_date='0000-00-00'
```

Comment: Doesn't filter out the rows where an id has a close_date that's a zero date.

Comment: @OMG zero date is not require as in question

Comment: Quote: "I do not want any of the left table records to be shown, and if there are NO right table records with a close_date of 0000-00-00"